# Send command back to variable without outputting to terminal and checking if ssl is up using openssl good solution?

Tags: ruby, docker, openssl

I have the following code which checks that the vault docker ssl server is up and running by using the openssl command and seeing if the word "CONNECTED" is in the response:

```
ssl_check = `docker exec vault /bin/sh -c "echo '' | openssl s_client -connect localhost:4556 | grep CONNECTED"`
unless ssl_check.include? "CONNECTED"
   raise 'Issues with starting SSL in vault... Aborting unit tests!'
end
```

The problem is, it outputs the `openssl` command response to the screen. So i learned i can redirect the output to `/dev/null` using `2>&1` which also allows for error redirection:

```
ssl_check = `docker exec vault /bin/sh -c "echo '' | openssl s_client -connect localhost:4556 >> /dev/null 2>&1"`
unless ssl_check.include? "CONNECTED"
   raise 'Issues with starting SSL in vault... Aborting unit tests!'
end
```

Now the command no longer prints to the screen, but the contents are not stored in the variable. I'm not a linux novice, but more like at a mid level understanding.

**How do i get the contents to the variable and not print to the screen so i can see if the word CONNECTED is included**

Also, is this prone to errors (my solution)? **IS there a better way to determine if ssl is up using openssl command than seeing if the word CONNECTED is in the response?**

Comment: Once it's ready, how do you connect to it?  Can you just try making a connection (with `Net::HTTP` or with whatever client library you'd use) and see if it succeeds?

Comment: @DavidMaze this is in a rakefile that prepares unit testing with rspec. for some reason, when i try to use the docker network ip locally its failing so im logging into the container and using openssl. can you help with the original problem? how do i get the openssl command output to a variable and not print to a screen? Thanks!